# text processing - Extracting using cshell and awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a long file containing the following lines repeatedly randomly throughout the file

```
$CROSS_BEAM_PROPERTY_281
POINT,201656,,-41.0213,-1.00928
POINT,201657,,-37.8216,-4.15746
POINT,201658,,-5.40451,-51.3106
POINT,201659,,-4.24517,-52.0837
POINT,201660,,-1.74418,-53.1687
POINT,201661,,2.03505,-51.2474
SET3,9,POINT,201670,201683,THRU,201701,201682
PBMSECT,1501,150,CP
        OUTP=8,
        BRP=9,
        T=1.3,
        T(1)=[1.3,PT=(201656, 201657)],
        T(2)=[1.3,PT=(201657, 201658)],
$CROSS_BEAM_PROPERTY_109
POINT,201660,,-1.74418,-53.1687
POINT,201661,,2.03505,-51.2474
POINT,201662,,4.249589,-48.9936
POINT,201663,,7.70361,-48.5562
POINT,201664,,9.169905,-48.7962
POINT,201665,,30.79493,-53.7184
POINT,201666,,33.52191,-53.1064
POINT,201667,,27.54975,-45.6262
PBMSECT,1500,150,CP
        OUTP=6,
        BRP=7,
        T=1.3,
        T(1)=[1.3,PT=(201610, 201611)],
        T(2)=[1.3,PT=(201611, 201612)],
```

For each `CROSS_BEAM_PROPERTY`, i would like to extract the `POINT`'s 4th and 5th column as an variable array so i can do further processing with it in one go? How do i extract them using cshell awk or sed?

Edit:
Just an overview, in the text file, there are a lot of `CROSS_BEAM_PROPERTY_XX`and the `POINT` defines the location in x and y. The example above is just a snippet of the file with two cross beam property. I would like to save for each `CROSS_BEAM_PROPERTY_XX` the 4th column into an array. With the array i could do some further calculation to extract the max value, min value or sum value of the array.

I managed to extract all the 4th column and sum it up using the line below.

```
cat $file | awk -F ',' '$1 == "POINT" {sum += $4} END {print sum}'
```

But this sums all the 4th column from all `POINT` entries in the text file. It does not separate for each `CROSS_BEAM_PROPERTY_XX`. Besides sum, i would also like to identify the max and min value in the 4th column for each `CROSS_BEAM_PROPERTY` - hence the need of an array.

Desired output:

```
-88.20171
113.280564
```

Is it also possible to get desired output for max of the 4th column as below?

```
2.03505
33.52191
```

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you're looking for. You should add what you expect the output to be for the given example input.

Comment: `csh`? Have you considered switching to something more robust/usable (e.g. `bash`, `zsh` etc)? `csh` is widely considered to be an inferior shell. Also, what do you mean by a variable array? Showing an example of awk/sed output would help.

Comment: So you want to store the sum by groups and by columns? That is, the sum of col 4 from the block of _CROSS_BEAM_PROPERTY_281_ (-88.2017), etc?

Comment: Yes that is the desired output. I have edited the post to include this

Answer (score 1):

```
 cat $file | awk -F "," '/^\$CROSS/,/^PBMSECT/{if($0~/CROSS/){v=$0};if($0~/^POINT/){p[v]+=$4}}END{for(i in p){print p[i]}}'
```

This outputs the first requested output:

```
-88.20171
113.280564
```

And for the second output you reqested the following will do:

```
cat $file | awk -F "," '/^\$CROSS/,/^PBMSECT/{if($0~/CROSS/){v=$0};if($0~/^POINT/){if($4>p[v]){p[v]=$4}}}END{for(i in p){print p[i]}}'
```

You could include the cross_beam_property in the output to make the output data nicer

```
$ cat $file | awk -F "," '/^\$CROSS/,/^PBMSECT/{if($0~/CROSS/){v=$0};if($0~/^POINT/){p[v]+=$4}}END{for(i in p){printf("%s\t%f\n", i, p[i])}}'
$CROSS_BEAM_PROPERTY_281        -88.201710
$CROSS_BEAM_PROPERTY_109        113.280564
```

Comment: The output works! But somehow when i ran it it gives out 
113.281 first, then the next line is -88.2017

Comment: I added a printf to make the output sorting irrelevant.

Comment: i am still getting $CROSS_BEAM_PROPERTY_109 as the first line. Is it because i am using tcsh and not bash?

Comment: @nabilishes odd, Im not sure. Does it still happen if you ditch the cat command and put $file at the end of the awk command?

Comment: yeah it gives out the same result.  $CROSS_BEAM_PROPERTY_109        113.280564 as the first line

Comment: I cannot repeat your result on either OpenBSD ksh or centos bash or cygwin bash.  Your issue is somehow related to your environment, that is, the code is fine.

Comment: I am running/using it on Centos tsch. However, I tried running it at home using Win10 WSL Ubuntu bash and the sorting works.

Comment: @nabilishes `/^\$CROSS/,/^PBMSECT/` is an idiomatic way to say: print from a line which matches the pattern `/^\$CROSS/` and up to a line which matches pattern `/^PBMSECT/`.

Comment: @nabilishes `{if($0~/CROSS/){v=$0}` is the way to store the whole line once within an `if`. It may not be necessary or you could use another hash to store data in `p`, but it is fine.

Comment: @nabilishes chances are that you have Bash in your CentOS. Try and run this script on that, instead of tsch :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for based on your explanation, but if you want to get the 4th and 5th column of each `POINT` row you can easily do that with `sed`:

```
sed -n -e 's/^POINT,[^,]*,[^,]*,//p' data.csv
```

This produces the following output from your example data:

```
-41.0213,-1.00928
-37.8216,-4.15746
-5.40451,-51.3106
-4.24517,-52.0837
-1.74418,-53.1687
2.03505,-51.2474
-1.74418,-53.1687
2.03505,-51.2474
4.249589,-48.9936
7.70361,-48.5562
9.169905,-48.7962
30.79493,-53.7184
33.52191,-53.1064
27.54975,-45.6262
```

If you want to put this data into an array, you can use process substitution like so:

```
set array=`sed -n -e 's/^POINT,[^,]*,[^,]*,//p' data.csv`
```

You can then access this data via the `array` variable, e.g.:

```
foreach point (${array})
echo ${point}
end
```

Of course you could do the same thing using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}/^POINT/{print $4,$5}' data.csv
```

Or even just using `grep` and `cut`:

```
cat data.csv | grep '^POINT' | cut -d, -f4,5
```

Comment: Thanks Igal. I have edited my post and elaborate the question and expected output.  Is it possible to separate the array for each CROSS_BEAM_PROPERTY