# Subtracting same column between two rows in awk

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I want to subtract the second line with the first line. The file is like this

tmptxt

```
A B 1 2 3 4 
C D 9 8 7 6
```

The desired output is

```
8 6 4 2
```

How to do this in awk?

I managed to output for  a single column only:

```
awk '{$temp=$3-prev3; prev3=$3}{print $temp}'
```

Comment: @John1024I managed to output for single column 
`awk '{$temp=$3-prev3; prev3=$3}{print $temp}'`. The only limitation is i am using tsch on CentOS. I know tsch is inferior compared to other interpreter but this is what i have to use. I tried this too but didnt get what i want `cat tmpfile | awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){$temp[i]=$i-prev; prev=$i;print $temp[i]}}'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with **awk**

```
awk '
    NR==1 {split($0,a)}
    NR==2 {split($0,b)}
    END {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%d ", b[i]-a[i]}
' input.txt
```

gives a result of

```
0 0 8 6 4 2
```

Since awk interpret strings without valid numbers as 0 during arithmetic operations, in case you want to remove the results in which the source field contains non-numeric values, you can do this by adding an additional condition.

```
awk '
    NR==1 {split($0,a)}
    NR==2 {split($0,b)}
    END {
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if(a[i] ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && b[i] ~ /^[0-9]+$/)
        printf "%d ", b[i]-a[i]
    }
' input.txt
```

gives a result of

```
8 6 4 2
```

Comment: thanks! this somehow help me in understanding lines splitting. However due to the nature of my workstation running on tsch, the arrangement of output is different on my side. It gives out with your first solution `6 4 2 0 0 8`

Comment: @nabilishes Hmm, that's odd, what's the awk version you are currently using `awk --version`?

Comment: Its GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: @nabilishes Thanks for the feedback, I can reproduce the same result using `gawk 3.1.7` with `bash`, it seems that the scanning order of array in awk is different in older versions. A safer solution is to replace `for(i in a)` with an explicit order `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)`

Comment: Thanks! this solution works like a charm. I previously had the same problem with the array sorting - [Here is the link of the same array sorting problem. It is in the comment section](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404133/text-processing-extracting-using-cshell-and-awk). Now i know its due to the version and not environment or interpreter

Answer (score 2):

Alternative ***Python*** solution:

```
python -c 'import sys; f=open(sys.argv[1],"r"); 
print(" ".join(str(int(d2)-int(d1)) 
for d1,d2 in zip(next(f).split()[2:], next(f).split()[2:]))); f.close()' file
```

The output:

```
8 6 4 2
```

Answer (score 0):

below command also provides same output.  l.txt contains the input which you have provided in question

```
for i in {1..6}; do awk -v i="$i" 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum=$i-sum}END{print sum}' l.txt ; done| tr "\n" " " | awk '{$1="";$2="";print $0}' | sed "s/^ //g"
```

output

```
8 6 4 2
```